# Delete char from input using start and end position javascript

Tags: javascript, input, position, selection

I am trying to delete text from input on a following way, and its not working in Mozilla, can anyone help?
In IE its working fine.

```
var start = txt.selectionStart;
var end = txt.selectionEnd;  
var selectedStr = txt.value.toString().substring(start, end);
txt.value = txt.value.toString().replace(selectedStr, "");
```

Comment: Why are you calling `toString` on strings? also: have you selected some part of the input? if so, is the substring unique, because `replace` will replace _the first match only_. If not: try `txt.value.substring(0,txt.selectionStart) + txt.value.substring(txt.selectionEnd)` to cut and past the input that wasn't selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to delete the selected text in a text input. You'll need two different approaches: one for IE < 9 and and one for other browsers that support `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties. Here's how:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hwG7f/1/

Code:

```
function deleteSelected(input) {
    input.focus();
    if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
        var start = input.selectionStart,
            end = input.selectionEnd,
            val = input.value;
        if (start != end) {
            input.value = val.slice(0, start) + val.slice(end);
            input.setSelectionRange(start, start);
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        document.selection.createRange().text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla (and other browsers) have a different implementations using [`document.selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection), [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getSelection) so you’ll need to adjust you code according to those methods/properties and legacy support table. You can use many libs out there that normalizes this for you.

Here is a code example that works in webkit:

```
var selectedStr = '';
if (window.getSelection) {
    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
}
```

Comment: @Asad the OP stated that the code was working in IE, was that a lie?

Comment: I have no idea if that is a lie, but implying that `document.selection.createRange()` is a substitute for `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` is wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, there are many browsers to consider.. however your statement that an input’s selection can’t be captured is also wrong, f.ex: http://jsfiddle.net/jM4ZY/ (chrome)

Comment: The main problem with this answer is that `window.getSelection()` is for selections within regular HTML content rather than inputs and textareas, which have a different selection API (except in old IE).

Comment: @David: True. Not in Firefox, Opera or IE 9 though. [The spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#dom-selection-stringifier) has nothing to say on this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the value isn't the correct way to approach this. Try taking the chunk of string preceding and following the selection:

```
var start = txt.selectionStart;
var end = txt.selectionEnd;
txt.value = txt.value.substring(0,start) + txt.value.substring(end);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/BuMUu/1/

Answer (score 0):

SelectionStart only works in IE9+.

Sorry, but why don't you just directly set it to "".

---

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear" />​

function clear() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
    txt.value = "";
}
$('#clear').click(function(){clear()});​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "yourString"
str = str.substring(1,str.length-1)
```

Comment: How has this anything to do with the question?